# Disable TLS <1.2 in WebView

Tags: android, ssl, webview, tls1.2

i want a webview to disable any connections with no TLS1.2 encryption, in Order to prevent MIT attacks.
min SDK ist currently 16, but i'am willing to go up to 23 if this should be nesseccary.
I'll be fine with a soloution like "checking a request onload" or onPagefinished, but i'm not even able to get the certificate of the current url, eccept if an error occurs, but this is not practicable.
Any suggestions?